# local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

i have an assignment that is asking me to create a module with 2 functions. The user is to enter the 3 sides of a triangle, and the two functions will check (a) if the input is valid and (b) what the area of the triangle is.

```
 def isValid(s1,s2,s3):

    if (s1 + s2<=s3):
         print("Input is invalid.")
    else:
         area(s1,s2,s3)


 def area(s1,s2,s3):
     p = (s1+s2+s3)/2
     a = (p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c))**(.5)
     print("The area of the triangle is: ",a)


s1 = eval(input("input s1: "))
s2 = eval(input("input s2: "))
s3 = eval(input("input s3: "))

isValid(s1,s2,s3)
```

im getting an error of: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced` before assignment

not sure where to go from here, getting a little confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the statement `a = (p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c))**(.5)`, what do you think `a` will be without having set it before that line?

Comment: wow. alright, thats all it took. thanks mate!

Comment: Don't add *THANK YOU EVERYONE FOR EXTREMELY QUICK RESPONSES. ALL FIXED. +1 all around.* as an edit!! Instead [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) any answer that you feel has completely explained the situation. Refer this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for example

Comment: Don't use `eval` to convert the input strings to numbers.

Comment: @user2469203 If your problem has been solved, you're supposed to ACCEPT an answer. Also: don't use `eval()`. Instead, you probably want to use `float()` or `int()` (if you're using Python 3).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variables `a`, `b` and `c` without having defined them, when calculating the area (stored in the variable `a` again):

```
a = (p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c))**(.5)
```

Perhaps you wanted to use `s1`, `s2` and `s3` here instead:

```
a = (p * (p - s1) * (p - s2) * (p - s3)) ** .5
```

Answer (score 0):

change function

```
 def area(s1,s2,s3):
     p = (s1+s2+s3)/2
     a = (p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c))**(.5)
     print("The area of the triangle is: ",a)
```

to

```
def area(s1,s2,s3):
    p = (s1+s2+s3)/2
    a = (p*(p-s1)*(p-s2)*(p-s3))**(.5)
    print("The area of the triangle is: ",a)
```